# How to wait after browser.keys() in WebdriverIO async mode?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, webdriver-io

I'm struggling to do something with async WebdriverIO v7 that in sync mode is quite easy.

Context: I'm using a React masked input component that has a bug (I can't fix that nor change the component), if I type too quickly the keys aren't registered and the cursor goes to the end, so I need to type at a relatively slow speed. When I use `await input.setValue('test')` the typing is too quick and it only types the first letter and can't type the rest, so I need to type every character separately and wait a little between keystrokes.

Basically I want to do this in async mode:

```js
[...textValue].forEach(char => {
  browser.keys(char);
  browser.pause(100);
});
```

I tried using `waitUntil()` but because this is a masked input, if I type `123456`, the value in the input will be `123.456.___-_` so I can't directly compare the two strings and wait until they are equal. Also, this seems like a lot of work for something that was so simple, so I'm wondering if there is a *better way*.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I tried comparing the saved input text so far on each `browser.key(char)` with the actual `input.getValue()` in the `waitUntil()` condition an it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I solved the problem. The issue was that the `forEach` loop can't wait for async operations, so I use a `for..of` loop now ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)).

```js
async typeSlowly (input, content) {
    let inputSoFar = '';

    for (const char of content) {
        inputSoFar = inputSoFar.concat(char);

        await browser.keys(char);
        await browser.waitUntil(
            async () => (await input.getValue()) === inputSoFar,
            {
                timeout: 500,
                timeoutMsg: 'expected text to be different after 500ms'
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I omitted the masking logic part because that's just a detail, the important bit here is the async waiting inside the loop.